# Упростить код работы с массивами

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм

Как упростить код работы с массивами, чтобы:

- сложность алгоритма была проще (больше быстродействие)
- код был легко читаемым

Принцип работы функции `getMinMaxValue` :
Проходится по массиву **`arr_1`** *`(BaseObject)`* с объектами *`(ParentObject)`* и внутри них по массивам **`items`** *`(Item[])`*

Записывает минимальное `value` из массива ***items*** в массив `minArr`
Записывает максимальное `value` из массива ***items*** в массив `maxArr`

Возвращает объект с полями:
`min` и значением - результат суммы всех чисел в `minArr`
`max` и значением - результат суммы всех чисел в `maxArr`

```
    const arr_1 = [
      {
        id: 1,
        type: 'cat',
        items: [
          {
            id: '1_1',
            ratio: '5',
            value: 100
          },
          {
            id: '1_2',
            ratio: '10',
            value: -30
          },
          {
            id: '1_3',
            ratio: '5',
            value: 200
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        type: 'dog',
        items: [
          {
            id: '1_1',
            ratio: '5',
            value: 200
          },
          {
            id: '1_2',
            ratio: '10',
            value: -60
          },
          {
            id: '1_3',
            ratio: '5',
            value: 300
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        type: 'rat',
        items: [
          {
            id: '1_1',
            ratio: '5',
            value: 100
          },
          {
            id: '1_2',
            ratio: '10',
            value: -150
          },
          {
            id: '1_3',
            ratio: '5',
            value: 100
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
    
    function getMinMaxValue() {
      const minArr = []
      const maxArr = []
    
      arr_1.forEach((elem) => {
        let min = +Infinity
        let max = -Infinity
    
        elem.items.forEach((item) => {
          const val = item.value
          min = min > val ? val : min
          max = max > val ? max : val
        })
    
        minArr.push(min)
        maxArr.push(max)
      })
    
      return {
        min: minArr.reduce((acc, num) => acc + num, 0),
        max: maxArr.reduce((acc, num) => acc + num, 0),
      }
    }
```

Типы:

```
type BaseObject = ParentObject[]

interface ParentObject {
  id: number
  type: string
  items: Item[]
}

interface Item {
  id: string
  ratio: string
  value: number
}
```

Comment: `minArr` и `maxArr` обязательны по условию задачи или важен результат?

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey важен результат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант без minArr и maxArr:

```
function getMinMaxValue() {
  const ret = {min: 0, max: 0}

  arr_1.forEach((elem) => {
    let min = +Infinity
    let max = -Infinity

    elem.items.forEach((i) => {
      min = min > i.value ? i.value : min
      max = max > i.value ? max : i.value
    })

    ret.min += min
    ret.max += max
  })

  return ret
}
```

**UPD**

Еще один вариант, более быстрый, но возможно менее читабельный:

```
function getMinMaxValue() {
  const ret = {min: 0, max: 0}

  arr_1.forEach((elem) => {
    ret.min += elem.items.reduce((a,b) => a.value < b.value ? a : b).value
    ret.max += elem.items.reduce((a,b) => a.value > b.value ? a : b).value
  })

  return ret
}
```

Сравнение производительности:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На диаграмме исходный вариант и два предложенных.

Comment: я бы ещё от этого `let min = +Infinity` избавился.

Comment: @tym32167 Да, и от второго forEach заодно. Но боюсь критерий "код был легко читаемым" под угрозой.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey объясните пожалуйста по графику. Здесь чем выше значение, тем хуже? И по коду какие какие варианты функций относятся к #1, #2, и #3

Comment: @HaZcker чем выше значение, тем больше операций в секунду, т.е. быстрее работает функция. #1 - исходный вариант, приведённый Вами в вопросе, #2 и #3 - предложенные мною два варианта.